# Mathematical Induction and multple

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that 41^n-14^n is a multiple of 27
I tried to factorise 41^n-14^n but 41 is a prime.  How should I go about

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
Notice that

$$41\equiv 14\mod 27$$